# Color one point with several colors in r ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I plot as the attached figure, i.e. plot the geom_point as radar/star? Not necessarily showing different size for each segment.

[image: Several colors for one point]

Comment: Not straightforward in ggplot2 alone. This geom in `ggforce` add-on package looks helpful: https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_arc_bar.html

Comment: could you add a little data, that you'd like to have plotted. Looks like an interesting task

Comment: Thanks for the response. Suppose we use red for A, blue for B and green for C. Just to plot points "AB" (1/2red and 1/2 blue),"AC"(1/2red, 1/2 green) and "ABC" (1/3 red, 1/3 blue and 1/3 green)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the data!

I played around a little with `ggforce` as suggested by Jon Spring (comment above)

```r
library(ggforce)

df=data.frame(point=c("AB","AC","ABC"),
              x=1:3, # x coordinate of point center
              y=c(0.5,2,0.5),# y coordinate of point center
              A=c(0.5,0.5,1/3), # I chose different values 
              B=c(0.7,0,1/4),   # to make the resulting plot
              C=c(0,0.5,1/3))   # a little more interesting

df=pivot_longer(df,cols=c(A,B,C),names_to = "colorby",values_to = "amount")
df$radius=sqrt(df$amount) # since we have a number represented by area
ggplot(df)+
  geom_polygon(aes(x=x,y=y),color="black",fill=NA,size=2)+ # draws the line connecting the points
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0=x,y0=y,r0=0,r=radius,amount=amount,fill=colorby),stat="pie")+
  coord_equal()+ # so one gets actually circles
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("A"="red","B"="blue","C"="green"))
```

[image]

If you want only "pie charts" you can just set `r=1` (or another appropriate value)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is as close as you can get just in ggplot2:

```
sizes <- expand.grid(size = 8, stroke = 2)
ggplot(sizes, aes(size, stroke, size = size, stroke = stroke)) + 
geom_point(shape = 16, colour = "red") +
geom_point(shape = 10, colour = "blue")
```

or

```
sizes <- expand.grid(size = 8, stroke = 2)
ggplot(sizes, aes(size, stroke, size = size, stroke = stroke)) + 
geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "red", colour = "blue") +
geom_point(shape = 10, colour = "blue")
```

You can get a radar/star with multiple colors, but not more than two colors (border and fill).

[image]